# css code to fix the width and height - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using carousel on my web application. Currently I have two graphs, when user click on the next arrow second graph is shown as shown in [demo here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/tPKXHeN3JWyqZgOtrTTS?p=preview)
Second graph width and height got reduced. I could not able to figure out how can I fix the width and height so that it wont get reduced when clicked on next arrow. 
I have gone through this link [Bootstrap carousel resizing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357306/bootstrap-carousel-resizing-image/24325781) but it didn't worked for me. Please advice how to fix the width and height when carousel, (when carousel is used then size getting reduced for second shown graph as shown in the demo above.

js code:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div id='id1' class="item active">
      <table style="width:100%;height:80%;">
      <tr>
     <td id="id1td"  ng-controller="myController1">
      <div google-chart chart="myChart" style="height:100%; width:100%;" align="center"/>
   </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>

    <div id='id2' class="item" ng-controller="myController2">
    <table style="width:100%;height:90%;">
      <tr style="height:5%;">
       <td>
         <h1>Title and some content goes here----</h1>
         </td>
    <tr style="height:85%;">

    <td id="id2td">
    <div google-chart chart="myChart" style="height:100%; width:100%;" align="center"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>

    </div> 

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
       <span class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" >
                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                     </span>
                                     <span class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set in options width and height to chart area:

```
chartArea: {
            'height': '200',
            'width': '200'
        }
```

Comment: Please find my working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/tPKXHeN3JWyqZgOtrTTS?p=preview. Its not reflecting with your code. When we click the next arrow the size of the graph is reduced. Any advice?thanks.

Comment: Did it worked for you? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YWK8B2XXn1W2B1CrHAPw?p=preview - I changed not chart area, but the whole height-width, check

Comment: You can try to play with width, make it wider. (if you don't need it ti be responsive)

Comment: but now both image size got reduced, how can I increase width and height to 100% for both the images?

Comment: In my cast I think implementing the solution mentioned in link http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/fz66o4L0/ would be difficult. Is there any solution which can be done without modifying js code.Appreciate your help.

Comment: I am not sure but when i open inspect element the graph comes original height and width you can see with use of `f12` or `ctrl + shift + i`

Comment: @LokeshGupta  - exactly..i too can see that.hmm but without inspect you can click next arrow, the second graph width and height is reduced. Any suggestions? Can we set width and height to 100% for both the graphs.

Comment: @Olga - please see the modified code https://plnkr.co/edit/zOFuntzd5Uzoo1bPNz57?p=preview as suggested,Still its not working, the second graph width and height is not increase. Any suggestions would be helpful.