# Stop bootstrap carousel from scaling the image

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel with some css that keeps the height to 500px. When I upload an image and show this in the carousel it scales with the carousel. It stretches and doesn't look good. Its like a 100x100 image or 64x64 even. How would I make it so my images dont stretch but stay the same size regardless(no scaling up).

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Carousel

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($tool->images); $i++)
                @if($i == 0)
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{$i}}" class="active"></li>
                @else
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{$i}}"></li>
                @endif
            @endfor
        </ol>


        <div class="carousel-inner">
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($tool->images); $i++)
                @if($i == 0)
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{ base64_encode($tool->images[$i]->bytes) }}"/>
                    </div>
                @else
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{ base64_encode($tool->images[$i]->bytes) }}"/>
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endfor
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>
```

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357306/bootstrap-carousel-resizing-image?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @mlegg this still resizes my image, which I don't want

Comment: when you changed your code did you clear the browser cache when the page opened with your new code?

Comment: @mlegg yes I did clear the cache. This is what it looks like: https://gyazo.com/4f9ad1959429a80136e2c8d11185f7ef and the image you see is actually 512x512

Comment: your inline bootstrap class `w-100` is explicitly forcing !important width of 100%;