# How do I adjust bootstrap carousel to resize images and make images linkable?

Tags: carousel, slideshow

I'm trying to build my website, and so far have found some answers in this site that have helped me out, but I keep running into some roadblocks.

Currently, I'm making a boot strap carousel and found ways to have the carousel resize the image height using this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461191/10654813

```
<head>
<style>.carousel-inner > .item > img { width:100%; height:570px; } </style>
</head>
```

The problem I'm having now, is that images with different widths are stretched out. What code do I need so the width of the images is respected?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>.carousel-inner>.item > img {width:100%; height:100%;} </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_60hiP6f26VTAhBtoXmVV1ogtQZW_l4q">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1NNF4sPI3Z0rieJ4moFnpWM9w-c4TUnIt">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=14Vn0Qa3jKJ9e0GvOxRlHFAoMJ2ElACbE">
      </div>

  <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nIwPiI5pO3lpXaEzddXRdhYMIOznYwBI">
      </div>

  <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nVy7T-10TrpYgdFbSZz356SpT9JJWvWS">
      </div>

  <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1s2CnnBlNDBzR2XuF53wQqt3lMQXS5z8a">
      </div>

  <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=19uPB4nECcIySfAQ48WwaLtm1jkxMzzQM">
      </div>

  <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=18eQZcE7U1Sz4xgXJ_jE2uUnudWI6W79O">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17qqNdGtcLdqnWwl_TAkzZIw-kagBd250">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=15KMQit_RIiHfyLocGO6jwhnmf_lrUPne">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1A3LocibiAvtRj931vPZowZ5hOqmZ9bXu">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1vJrKy2x7Jj2nY5TzuNfw1VPQn7hJXeoM">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1wU2iv5IxUhHallwdzOHXqbwn6ufT-rNx">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1zbCjc0Y1uCiMNLwm-7k7U-q9lMYWoeR6">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1OQ7UnEvXl1pZww9hOJE1LZy-K9x28VY9">
      </div>


 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1VHLX_7fuu_i0-1zlsYNbJZxTI-RebH7X">
      </div>

  <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1gml2FIqIddrQGz8gaB8B_ziYb682ko_e">
      </div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1mrHn0jMeCuXUpQDafcm64fi03Vx7uucw">
      </div>

    </div>


    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `width: 100%` to `max-width: 100%` should do the trick.

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 570px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This solved the stretching issue. Is there a way to make images of less width to stay centered?

Comment: Yes, add `margin: 0 auto;` in the above declaration block.