# Why does the size of background image change upon carousel being toggled?

Tags: html, css, debugging, bootstrap-4

I'd like to know why the `background-image` gets bigger vertically upon being going from `url/path` to `url/path2`.  I want it to remain the same when it toggles through all the images.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**Snippet**

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

```css
.topSection {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/owXXD.jpg");
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
    width: 17em;
    margin: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container topSection">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide row" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active col-6">
                <img class="d-block w-10" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0J5g.png" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-10" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pzi6.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-10" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pzi6.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: provide images first or any pen that help us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap carousel resizing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357306/bootstrap-carousel-resizing-image)

Comment: @NishargShah images have been provided

Comment: your 1st image height is less so it create effect like that

Comment: @NishargShah yeah, I'd like to know how I would fix that so it can remain the same regardless of height.

Comment: let me fix this wait a while

Comment: @NishargShah no problem

Comment: i will add answer but your question looks not good so i change it

Comment: let me give my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the height of .topSession is max-height: 100% it will resize based on the size of the image, so what you got to do is define the height of your class like:

```
.topSection {
 padding-top: 20px;
 background-image: url("https://d2d00szk9na1qq.cloudfront.net/Product/40a055c9-72b6-4e07-aaa8-0eaf956f297c/Images/Large_0348615.jpg");
 width: 100%;
 height: 60%;
 position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: your parent height not be toggled but your child ( img ) height toggled till now, your answer not be correct from my side