# Is there a way to resize a carousel image without losing the image quality?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I currently have three images in my carousel with a this html tag wrapped in them: "

I have looked at online solutions but nothings works. I have played with the height and width, but it end up a distorted image

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="carousel-item active">
                     <img class="img-fluid" src="img/classic%20physique_frontshotflexed.JPG">
                     <!--Img-fluid resize image while w-100 makes it a feel screen MUST CHANGE LATER -->
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h5>My First Competition</h5>
```

My expected result is to have a perfect image with an height of 570px instead of the auto height size. Any way I can achieve that will be well appreciated

Comment: Can you provide your CSS? It's hard to guess what is happening without the CSS. To avoid distorting images, you must resize one dimension only while allowing the other dimension to remain set to auto. If you resize both the width and the height at the same time (set to 100%, etc), then it will distort the image to fill the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do with image problems like this is re-configure the dimensions in photo editing software like photoshop or gimp.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17357643/11755791
Does this help? You might have to make your CSS tags more specific to get them to pick up.

Comment: I have tried that. It only set the image to the left side of the carousel. I appreciate it tho

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers are usually better when you explain why another question might be helpful, or even quote the other question using the > symbol. Also, for future reference, please note that when you get to 50 reputation, you will be able to comment very small criticisms, clarification requests, or even helpful links.